# Inconsistent count after window lead function, and filter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

**Edit 2:**

I've reported this as an issue to spark developers, I will post status here when I get some.

---

I have a problem that been bothering me for quite some time now.

Imagine you have a dataframe with several milions of records, with these columns:

- df1:

  - start(timestamp)
  - user_id(int)
  - type(string)

I need to define duration between two rows, and filter on that duration and type.
I used window lead function to get the next event time (that define end for current event), so every row now gets start and stop times.
If NULL (last row for example), add next midnight as stop.
Data is stored in ORC file (tried with Parquet format, no difference)

This only happens with multiple <del>executors</del> cluster nodes,  for example AWS EMR cluster or local docker cluster setup.
If I run it on single instance (local on laptop), I get consistent results every time.
Spark version is 3.0.1, both in AWS and local and docker setup.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val w = Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy("start")
val ts_lead = coalesce(lead("start", 1) .over(w), date_add(col("start"), 1))

val df2 = df1.
    withColumn("end", ts_lead).
    withColumn("duration", col("end").cast("long")-col("start").cast("long"))

df2.where("type='B' and duration>4").count()
```

Every time I run this last count, I get different results.
For example:

- run 1: 19359949
- run 2: 19359964

If I run every filter separately, everything is OK and I get consistent results.
But If I combine them, inconsistent.

I tried to filter to separate dataframe, first duration then type and vice versa, no joy there also.
I know that I can cache or checkpoint datframe, but it's very large dataset and I have similar calculations multiple times, so I can't really spare time and disk space for checkpoints and cache.

Is this a bug in spark, or am I missing something?

**Edit:**

I have created sample code with dummy random data, so anyone can try to reproduce.
Since this sample use random numbers, it's necessary to write dataset after generation and re-read it.
I user for loop to generate set because when I tried to generate 25.000.000 rows in one pass, I got out of memory error.
I saved it to s3://bucket , here it's masked with **your-bucket**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val getRandomUser = udf(()=>{
    val users = Seq("John","Eve","Anna","Martin","Joe","Steve","Katy")
   users(scala.util.Random.nextInt(7))
})

val getRandomType = udf(()=>{
    val types = Seq("TypeA","TypeB","TypeC","TypeD","TypeE")
    types(scala.util.Random.nextInt(5))
})

val getRandomStart = udf((x:Int)=>{
    x+scala.util.Random.nextInt(47)
})

for( a <- 0 to 23){
        // use iterator a to continue with next million, repeat 1 mil times
        val x=Range(a*1000000,(a*1000000)+1000000).toDF("id").
            withColumn("start",getRandomStart(col("id"))).
            withColumn("user",getRandomUser()).
            withColumn("type",getRandomType()).
            drop("id")

        x.write.mode("append").orc("s3://your-bucket/random.orc")
}

val w = Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy("start")
val ts_lead = coalesce(lead("start", 1) .over(w), lit(30000000))

val fox2 = spark.read.orc("s3://your-bucket/random.orc").
    withColumn("end", ts_lead).
    withColumn("duration", col("end")-col("start"))

// repeated executions of this line returns different results for count 
fox2.where("type='TypeA' and duration>4").count()
```

My results for three consecutive runs of last line were:

- run 1: 2551259
- run 2: 2550756
- run 3: 2551279

Every run different count

Comment: can you reproduce it with a manually created dataframe? if so, post it so we can reproduce locally and you will be much likely to get help. Note that you can run with local[4] for example to have parallel execution in your laptop

Comment: @Selnay, I've edited post and added dummy random data and still managed to reproduce this problem. Even used integers instead of timestamps... 
Also, I wrongly said that it only happens with multiple executors, it goes ok on single computer with any number of executors (I have 12 cores and used local[11]. It happens on multiple cluster nodes, like EMR or docker setup with one master and several worker nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your issue locally.

As far as I understand, the issue is that you are filtering by `duration` in this sentence:
`fox2.where("type='TypeA' and duration>4").count()`

and `duration` is generated randomly. I understand that you are using a seed, but if you parallelise that, you do not know which random value will be added to each `id`.

For example, if 4 generated numbers were `21, 14, 5, 17`, and the `id`s were `1, 2, 3, 4`, the start column sometimes could be:

```
1 + 21
2 + 14
3 + 5
4 + 17
```

and sometimes could be:

```
1 + 21
4 + 14
3 + 5
2 + 17
```

this will lead to different `start` values, and hence different `duration` values, ultimately leading to changes in the final `filter` and `count` because order in dataframes is not guaranteed when running in parallel.

Comment: I crated random data just to generate some data, because I cannot share real data. 
The same thing happens with data that is not random.
Since random data is used in this example, it is crucial to write data frame first to avoid different values on repeated runs. 
So first write dataframe once it's generated. After that, you do not need to run anything but read, apply window functions, calculate durations and apply filter

Comment: I cannot reproduce it locally then. If I execute only the last sentence I always get the same result.

Comment: Of course, if running single node. Requirement is to user multi node cluster.
BTW, what is your spark version? this setup is on 3.0.1 EMR on AWS